# How to have more than five torrents downloading concurrently with transmission?

Tags: download, bittorrent, transmission

I've installed transmission on my Raspbmc distro and it's been working great. The only thing I've noticed is that it can only download five torrents concurrently; anything after that is queued. I've tried running `transmission-remote -h` and looking through all the possible options, and the closest things I can find to changing this option are `--downlimit` and `--no-downlimit`, but those pertain to the *speed* of the downloads, not the *number* of downloads. Is there any way to change the limit on the *number* of torrents download at one time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the file `~/.config/transmission/settings.json` and update the value of `"download-queue-size": 5`.

See [documentation](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles).

For e.g.:

```
$ grep 'download-queue' ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
    "download-queue-enabled": true,
    "download-queue-size": 5,
```