# How to configure the number of concurrent downloads with Vuze?

Tags: download, file-sharing, bittorrent, p2p, vuze

How do I edit the quantity of downloads?  Not number of connections, not maximum speed, but number of files being actively downloaded?

See also:

[How to have more than five torrents downloading concurrently with transmission?](https://superuser.com/q/679167/55747)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I edit the quantity of downloads?

> By default, Vuze allows you to perform a maximum of 5 simultaneous
>   downloads.
>
> To increase this value:
>
> - Open Vuze > Click on the Tools Menu > Options
> - Select the "Queue" tab
>
> In the right pane next change the values in the following fields:
>
> - Max simultaneous downloads
> - Max active torrents
>
>   [image]
>
>   (Setting the value to 0- implies that Vuze will accept an unlimited
>     amount of torrents and downloads)
> - Click on Apply
>
> Note that: to enable this option, Vuze must be [configured to
>   Intermediate or Advanced Mode](https://ccm.net/faq/13217-vuze-switch-to-intermediate-or-advanced-mode).

Source [Vuze - Increase the maximum number of maximum downloads](https://ccm.net/faq/13434-vuze-increase-the-maximum-number-of-maximum-downloads)